# Uniquness of convex combination

Tags: algebra-precalculus, convex-analysis

Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers such that $0<a<b$ and let $x$ be such that $a<x<b$. How can I determine $a_x$ and $b_x$ such that

$$
x=a_x\cdot a+b_x\cdot b~~,~~a_x\geq 0,~~b_x\geq 0,~~a_x+b_x=1?
$$

Do $a_x$ and $b_x$ exist unique? I know that a possible solution is

$$
a_x = \frac{b-x}{b-a},~b_x = \frac{x-a}{b-a},
$$

but I do not know how to derive it and if this is the unique solution.

Comment: Just replace $b_x$ by $1 - a_x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider
$$
a_x\cdot a+b_x\cdot b = x\\
a_x+b_x=1
$$
as a linear system in $a_x$ and $a_y$. This system is easily solved for all $x$, provided $a\ne b$, and it gives the solution you have. This proves it is unique.

Answer (score 1):

Write $a_x=1-b_x$, and substitute into $x=a_x\cdot a + b_x\cdot b$ to get:

$$x=(1-b_x)a + b_xb$$
$$x=a+b_x(b-a)$$
$$b_x=\dfrac{x-a}{b-a}$$